# SQL Server 2012, Combine multiple fields into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've tried

```
'field1'+'field2'+'field3' as combination
```

and tried:

```
 ((((field_1||'_')||field_2_yes)||'_')||field_3_yes) AS combination
```

tried:

```
field1 || field2 as combination
```

i've also tried Concat, coalesce, can't seem to get it to work.
Also I am querying SQL server through excel if that helps.

Expected output is a column named `combination` with the `field1field2field3` data as the rows within combination column. I'm am not trying to create the literal string `field1field2field3` but combine the data from these fields into a string and display in new column.

The issue is with the data types as to why these fields are not combining.

Comment: Tried `column1 || column2 || column3`?

Comment: You are concatenating strings, not fields. Remove the single quotes. Both Coalesce and Concat work by the way

Comment: `I'm am not trying to create the literal string field1field2field3 ` that's exactly what this query created though

Comment: What is the datatype of the fields?

Comment: What does "can't seem to get it to work" mean? Why do you have single quotes around your column names?

Comment: This kind of concatenation is somewhat of a display issue for a UI, and not a db selection issue.

Comment: @jarlh , yes ive tried, doesnt work.

Comment: It doesn't work because that's not valid syntax in SQL Server. Don't put apostrophes around your column names. That's the solution. You've literally done everything except valid SQL Server syntax... `field1 + field2`...

Comment: You seem to need help and we can do that, but you need to give us some information. When you say things like "I can't get it to work" you might as well say nothing because it provides zero information. That is like taking your car to the mechanic and saying "my car won't run" and expecting them to just figure out the problem. Usually you would do something like "my car always turns to the left" or "it turns over but won't start on cold days". You see the difference?

Comment: @SQL_M  , Varchar works fine, the `INT CONSTRAINT` are whats causing error. I am casting the troubled fields like so `cast(field1 as varchar(50)) as fieldneeded`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try without aposthropes?:

```
select combination = (field1 + field2)
from table
```

In case you need to put a space between the values, if field1 and field2 is varchar, then you can do:

```
select combination = (field1 + ' ' + field2)
from table
```

If field1 and field2 is not varchar, then you can cast like below and use in your main query:

```
cast(field1 as varchar(50))
```

Comment: Tried this, doesnt work. Also a couple notes, I am querying through excel, characters are both letters and numbers, and fields I rename prior to doing the query , not sure if that would affect this.

Comment: after testing this more, it seems like i can do this for one field.. ie  combination = (field1) ,when I add more fields I get an error

Comment: Telling us the error message would be more useful than "I get an error".

Comment: The issue is the datatype on one of the fields, the fields that are already varchar are working but the fields that are `INT CONSTRAINT` not working even when I use above casting to varchar

Comment: figured it out, I have to cast as varchar in the actual line that I am making the combination field in

Comment: @ErayBalkanli yes thank you. was just mixing up where the varchar went.

Answer (score 2):

So do you want only to display 2 fields as a one field?

Field1 = 'hello'
field2 = 'world'

```
select field1 + field2 as concatfield from table
select concat(field1, field2) as concatfield from table
```

This will give you output like that:

```
helloworld
```

If you want to add space then try this:

```
  select field1 + ' ' + field2 as concatfield from table
  select concat(field1, ' ', field2) as concatfield from table
```

This will give you output like that:

```
hello world
```

And then exacly the same if you want to update a field in DB

```
 update table
 set concatfield =  field1 + ' ' + field2 --or concat(field1, ' ', field2)
 --where 1=1
```

Comment: I'm working with read-only db, no updating. The problem seems to be the datatype.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty basic

```
declare @Field varchar(10) = 'value' 
select @Field + @Field + @Field as comb 
select '@Field' + '@Field' + '@Field' as comp  

comb
------------------------------
valuevaluevalue

comp
------------------
@Field@Field@Field
```